# If our experience of time is due to entropic increase, wouldn't time pass differently in a fridge?

Tags: time

If (and that's a big if) I understand Carlo Rovelli's argument in his book [The Order of Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Order_of_Time_(book)), he seems to suggest that our perception of the flow of time is due to heat transfer as per the second law of thermodynamics.

Let me note here that he acknowledge that this is not an accepted view and that he has no scientific evidence for it (hence the question on philosophy not physics SE).

But an obvious objection to this claim (which he does not seem to address in the book) is that if the flow of time is simply a perspective of our relation with increased entropy, shouldn't time flow at a different pace where different rates of entropy are observed? Shouldn't time in my fridge run slower, for example, than time in my oven?

Comment: Time in your fridge arguably DOES run slower, for certain relevant metrics. A watch probably doesn't run slower, because for the physical mechanisms in a watch, the "entropy" at play in them is not changed by temperature, but for a Bacteria, say, the "entropy" at play DOES run slower - which is why fridges work.

Comment: I've also heard it said by Sean Carroll that entropy's relationship to time is exclusively about the direction of time, not about the speed of time. Entropy increases as time moves forward, but that doesn't say anything about how fast entropy increases as time moves forward.

Comment: @firtydank It would be very helpful if you could elaborate a bit on Rovelli's argument. - To which chapter and page in the book do you refer?

Comment: The problem is that we can't measure an absolute property called "time". We just become aware of the passage of time by watching periodic processes. So the operational definition of time is "What the clock reads". In our case we look at the groundstate hyperfine transition of a ceasium atom and define a second to be 9192631770 times that. So it's actually possible that the pace of time is different for different observers, the classic example being special relativity where moving and stationary observers perceive time differently. So qualitatively such a phenomena is possible.

Comment: @JoWehler - I fear I think it would be folly for me to try to summarize the claim since I do not really understand it myself. But there seems to be a wikipedia article related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_time_hypothesis with additional links

Comment: @TKoL - my understanding is that Rovelli is talking about clock time, not subjective time.  But perhaps you are right, maybe even the frequency of a ceasium atom are impacted by thermodynamic considerations that could be measured. It just seems odd to me that if thermal time *is* clock time, that clock time is surprisingly stable in the face of various thermodynamic situations and only seem to be affected by relativistic considerations like gravity and velocity, which in turn is not obviously related to the second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: Do you mean time as perceived by humans, time as defined by physicists, or time as "experienced" by microscopic mold colonies on a piece of fruit?

Comment: @firtydank he's specifically talking about the "perception of the flow of time", from my reading - and that could ostensibly be affected by temperature. The reason it's possibly not necessarily affected by temp. much for Humans is because the temperature inside our skull is regulated - in other words, even if we're in a freezer, our brain is still kept at a high temp and operates as if its at a higher temp regardless of the surrounding environment. It's completely feasible that, for *brains* that are capable of operating at lower temp, the experience of time changes.

Comment: I find it impossible to understand why a question like this one should be considered off-topic or outside of philosophy.